# custombox - how to use?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to use custombox ( http://dixso.github.io/custombox/ ). On the site it works, but then I downloaded it it looked like it didn't read some of the css.
I tried to use it following the instructions but iti didn't work either.
This is my code: (looks like it didn't put the last part where I loaded the script)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custombox.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="button">Click</div>
<div style="display:none;" class="open">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function( e ) {
        Custombox.open({
            target: '.open',
            effect: 'fadein'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: If this is your entire code, it is obvious why it does not work; because you have not included the js file! Else, it may be a good idea to show your entire code if it not too long or isolate the problem if it is.

Comment: ' (looks like it didn't put the last part where I loaded the script) ' - first post. It's strange, if I put the whole code it's divided in 3 parts automatically. The script is loaded. That's it.